# How To Set My Flash Project To Be Maximum Window Size?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I basically want the project to launch in full screen, but not the full screen where you don't even get to see your taskbar.

I tried using `stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` but it literally makes the project be full screen and not windowed.

**Question**:
Is there some option to make my project display at largest or maximum window size?

Comment: If you are running an AIR application, you can read **Capabilities.screenResolutionY** and **Capabilities.screenResolutionY** (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) to resize and position the app window accordingly. If you are running a content projector, try **fscommand("fullscreen", true);** (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html), but I'm pretty sure it's still a windowless fullscreen. Browser's Flash Plugin is not an application and can only do a regular fullscreen either.

Comment: As an alternative, use regular full screen but emulate (draw) a fake window header with a close button, maybe make also a minimize/resize button to go back to windowed mode.

Comment: BTW, it turns out that in AIR there's a method to actually maximize a window: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#maximize()